# Running Apache as Group only?

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I have a folder with files owned by: joe:www-data, joe belongs to the group.

Apache only seems to cooperate with www-data:www-data. Is there a way around this so I can keep the user as joe and the group as www-data?

Is it recommended to use this module below if I want to accomplish this task? Is this a good idea?

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What error are you actually encountering? You should be able to keep the html folders grouped as www-data and have Apache use them.

Comment: Well I am deploying with the login `joe`, and the file permissions are `joe:joe`, I want to be able to chown to `joe:www-data` (Yet Apache will only read if its `www-data:www-data`

Comment: What are the permissions on your files? Giving the files to group `www-data` won't help if they're not readable to the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to tell Apache to switch to your `www-data` group via the mechanism you found.

You could instead add `joe` to the `daemon` group and `chgrp -R daemon` the `DocumentRoot` containing the files you want to serve, but `daemon` is a general-purpose group. It's more secure to use a service-specific group, especially for so powerful a service as Apache.

Comment: I am going to try this tomorrow it sounds cool :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *apache2-mpm-itk* which allows to customize Apache *user* and *group* used for each *virtual host*.

*apt-get install apache2-mpm-itk*

*nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/mydomain.com
    Options -Indexes
    AssignUserID myuser mygroup
</VirtualHost>
```

See [Create and set up an Apache virtual host](http://en.open-lamp.com/create-and-set-up-an-apache-virtual-host/) for more details.